# Issue with Xamarin Grid Layout panel

Tags: xamarin

I am developing a simple app using Xamarin for Android. Currently I am using GridLayout to render my UI elements in the screen. But while compile it is showing error:

**Error 1#**

```
Error APT0000: No resource identifier found for attribute 'rowCount' in   
package 'android' (APT0000)
```

**Error 2#**

```
Error APT0000: No resource identifier found for attribute 'columnCount' in 
package 'android' (APT0000)
```

**Error 3#**

```
Error APT0000: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_row' in     
package 'android' (APT0000)
```

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"    
        android:rowCount="4"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
            android:text="Cell 0"
            android:textSize="14dip"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0" /> 
     <TextView
            android:text="Cell 1"
            android:textSize="14dip"
            android:layout_row="0"        
            android:layout_column="1" />
     <Space
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_width="50dp"        
            android:layout_height="50dp" />   
     <TextView
            android:text="Cell 2"
            android:textSize="14dip"
            android:layout_row="2"        
            android:layout_column="0" /> 
     <TextView
            android:text="Cell 3"
            android:textSize="14dip"        
            android:layout_row="2"        
            android:layout_column="1" />
     <Button 
            android:id="@+id/myButton" 
            android:text="@string/hello"        
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_column="0" />
</GridLayout>
```

Here is my environment:

Xamarin Studio: 5.9 (build 431) - latest build

Xamarin.Android: 5.1

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are targetting an android API version lower than 14 (GridLayout was introduced in 14 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html). If you go to project properties and increase the target API level to at least 14, it should be fine.

Most phones are 14 and above at this point, so you should be fine, hope that helps! If you need to target lower API levels, you can try the appcompat lib: https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-gridlayout

Comment: Getting similar error for another touch-screen attribute.  Is there a good way to map from the feature to the release ??

Comment: @mobibob - If you have diverging code paths for different releases, you can using preprocessor directives as described here (http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/part_4_-_platform_divergence_abstraction_divergent_implementation/#Android) for example #if __ Android_14 __ (code) #endif